# Best Practice For Storing Gmail Accessible Android Application Log

Tags: android

**What I Want**

I want to store a log for my application so when I receive bug reports, the log gets attached to the email.

**The Problem**

According to the Android documentation, files that you don't necessarily want the user to see or other applications to access need to be stored in the internal storage. However, there are applications I want to access it such as Gmail and other email applications for when the user emails me bug reports however I don't necessarily want the user having free access to it all of the time.

**Possible Workarounds**

1. I just bite the bullet and store the logs on the external storage from the start and allow the user to access them. However, this causes problems when no external storage is available.
2. I store the logs on the internal storage, which is always available if there's space, and copy them to external storage each time a bug report is submitted. This however defeats the private concept.

**My Question**

How do I store a file/files internally but also allow them to be made attachments for applications such as Gmail etc?

Is the saving to external storage solution a good idea or a stupid one?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Keep the logged information private to your app**. Also consider filtering out sensitive information from your log files (that is don't log usernames, passwords, ...). Next build a "report bug" option in your app where you can access this information.

**There is no need to expose this information.**

Also validate alternatives like [critercism](https://www.crittercism.com/) and consider if you really need to put this kind of work into solving this issue. Knowing that the **default android bug reports** have such an option and the Developer console has quite a lot of information about the crash that occurred.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the critercism. I hadn't heard of it. In an ideal world I would definitely deploy this into the app however there is the matter of cost. In regards to sensitive information, I wouldn't store it in the log files anyway. I'm more than happy to place it internal storage however its the issue of being able to attach it to external applications?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

You use the Android FileProvider.

Add this to your `manifest.xml` in the applications tag.

```
         <provider 
             android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
             android:authorities="insert_application_package_name_plus_identifier"
             android:exported="false"
             android:grantUriPermissions="true"
             android:readPermission="insert_application_package_name_plus_identifier.READ">
             <meta-data
                 android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                 android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
         </provider>
```

You then need to create a new resource xml file in `res/xml` called `provider_paths.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="logs"/>
</paths>
```

Then when it comes to attaching them to an email.

```
    emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] {insert_email_address_here});

    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    File directory = getFilesDir();
    File[] list = directory.listFiles();
    for (File f : list) {
        if (f.getName().contains("log") && f.getName().contains(".txt"))
            uris.add(FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "insert_application_package_name_plus_identifier",f));
    }

   emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);


    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Choose preferred email client."));
```

I hope this helps someone.